# Como saber qual o fireDate da próxima notificação agendada?

Tags: objective-c, push-notification

Eu gostaria de saber se tem um jeito de pegar o próximo `fireDate` a partir da data atual.

Eu tenho um método que cria a notificação e repete ela a cada determinado período. Como pego o próximo `fireDate`? Precisaria disso para exibir numa string.

```
- (void)criarNotificacao {
    NSDate *novaData = self.data;
    for (int i = 0; i < (24/self.intervalo); i++) {
        UILocalNotification *notificacao = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notificacao.fireDate = novaData;
        notificacao.alertBody = self.nome;
        notificacao.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notificacao.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notificacao.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
        notificacao.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notificacao];
        novaData = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(self.intervalo*3600) sinceDate:novaData];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A classe `UIApplication` possui a propriedade [`scheduledLocalNotifications`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/scheduledLocalNotifications), a qual possui uma lista com todas as notificações agendadas.

Você pode ter algo assim:

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *notifications = [application scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

E em cima deste *array*, obter a próxima notificação com base em sua data, resultando em um objeto `UILocalNotification`.

```
NSSortDescriptor *fireDateDesc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"fireDate" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sorted = [notifications sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[fireDateDesc]]
UILocalNotification *nextNotification =  [sorted objectAtIndex:0];
```